# Cannot install atom package api-blueprint-preview

Tags: python, node.js, atom-editor, apiblueprint

I have installed Python, npm (all added to the path), VS 2013 and try to install atom package called api-blueprint-preview.

```
PS X:\> apm install api-blueprint-preview

Installing api-blueprint-preview to C:\Users\mm\.atom\packages failed
runas@1.1.0 install C:\Users\MM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas
node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\MM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas>node "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\atom\app-0.179.0\resources\app\apm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
main.cc
runas_win.cc
C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\nan\nan.h(623): error C2039: 'ExternalAsciiStringResource' : is not a member of 'v8::String' (..\src\main.cc) [C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas\build\runas.vcxproj]
C:\Users\mm\.atom\.node-gyp\.node-gyp\0.21.0\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1809) : see declaration of 'v8::String'
C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\nan\nan.h(623): error C2065: 'ExternalAsciiStringResource' : undeclared identifier (..\src\main.cc) [C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas\build\runas.vcxproj]
C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\nan\nan.h(623): error C2065: 'resource' : undeclared identifier (..\src\main.cc) [C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas\build\runas.vcxproj]
C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\nan\nan.h(623): error C2448: 'NanNew' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition (..\src\main.cc) [C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas\build\runas.vcxproj]
C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\nan\nan.h(672): warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'int64_t' to 'int', possible loss of data (..\src\main.cc) [C:\Users\mm\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-115117-7008-ig28xb\node_modules\api-blueprint-preview\node_modules\pathwatcher\node_modules\runas\build\runas.vcxproj]
[...] a lot of errors like above [...]
gypnpm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\mm\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-0.179.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\bin\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mm\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\app-0.179.0\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "C:\\Users\\mm\\.atom\\.apm\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\mm\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\MM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\d-115117-7008-mb9spd\\package.tgz" "--target=0.21.0" "--arch=ia32" "--msvs_version=2013"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.3.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! runas@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the runas@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the runas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls runas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My boxs is running Windows 8.1.

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was a problem with package's dependencies which got fixed.

https://github.com/danielgtaylor/atom-api-blueprint-preview/issues/6